# getResources().getIdentifier Is not reading drawable image

Tags: java, android

I am using getResources().getIdentifier to retrieve a drawable image based on a description from JSON, but somehow is not reading it. I have another class where this is reading perfectly with the same code, but on this class is not reading.

Here is my code:

```
String image = obj.getDescr1().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(image + "n", "drawable", getPackageName());
    img1.setBackgroundResource(resId);
```

Can someone tell me where is the problem? I tried also:

```
MyActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier(image + "n", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

But no luck :(

Comment: what do you mean by *but on this class is not reading.* ?

Comment: Print the value of `image` and `resId` to logcat. Make sure that the image resource is named accordingly. Also inspect the `drawable` nested class of the generated `R.java` file for the resource identifier.

Comment: I have done that, the value of the image is correct, and the resId is different than 0

Comment: @ Blackbelt By "is not reading" it means doesn't display the image

Comment: Well, finally I afound that the problem was the type of layouts I was using. In the first class, where everyting is working I used a LinearLayout in the second one where the image was not displaying it was a GridLayout. When I change the second layout to a LinearLayout, boom, it was working!